# Phantom node package equivalent code for PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I'm having a hard time converting this code for it to be usable in a node server. So this code is written to run in a PhantomJS process (i.e. $: phantomjs index.js) but I want to run it in a node server using the package require("phantom"); I'm having a trouble getting these two callbacks to work however.

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(status){
    console.log("Load Finished");
};
page.onUrlChanged = function(){
    console.log("URL Changed");
};
```

Here is my pathetic attempt at trying to nodefy the whole situation.

```
  phantom.create(['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes','--load-images=no']).then(function(ph) {
    console.log("here");
    ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
      page.property('onResourceRequested', function(requestData, networkRequest) {
        console.log(requestData.url);
      });
      page.open('https://example.com/login').then(function(status) {
        console.log(status);
        if (status !== 'success') { console.log("failed connection")} else {

          page.evaluate(function() {
            document.getElementById('email').value = "stuff";
            document.getElementById('password').value = "things";
            setTimeout(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click(),5000);
            console.log("login attempt");
            setTimeout(document.URL, 2000);
          });
          page.onLoadFinished = function(status){
            console.log("Load Finished");
          };
          page.onUrlChanged = function(){
            console.log("url changed");
          };

        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Also the code works and gets the page and clicks the button, however the problem is after the phantom logs in, I need data from the next page which I was going to use the onUrlChanged and onLoadFinished to do.

Comment: To clarify, the functions I set for .onLoadFinished and .onUrlChanged in the nodejs phantom.create method never run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

page.onLoadFinished and page.onUrlChanged are callback functions that are executed **after** page has been opened, so it makes sense to assign them before opening an url.

It is also a useful habit to subscribe to console.log and error messages from a webpage.

```
  var phantom = require('phantom');
  phantom.create(['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes','--load-images=no']).then(function(ph) {
    console.log("here");
    ph.createPage().then(function(page) {

      page.property('onError',  function(msg, trace) {
          var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];
          if (trace && trace.length) {
            msgStack.push('TRACE:');
            trace.forEach(function(t) {
              msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
            });
          }
          console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
      });

      page.property('onConsoleMessage',  function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
        console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
      });

      page.property('onResourceRequested', function(requestData, networkRequest) {
        console.log(requestData.url);
      });

      page.property('onLoadFinished', function(status) {
        console.log("Load Finished with status " + status);
      });

      page.property('onUrlChanged', function(targetUrl) {
        console.log("URL changed to: " + targetUrl);
      });

      page.open('https://example.com/login').then(function(status) {

        if (status !== 'success') { console.log("failed connection")} else {

          page.evaluate(function() {
              document.getElementById('email').value = "email";
              document.getElementById('password').value = "password";

              setTimeout(function(){
                console.log("login attempt");
                document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();
              }, 5000);
            });

          });

        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Dude you're awesome. Thank you the problem I was having was that I wasn't using page.property('') I was using the phantomjs version.

Comment: Unfortunately I lack the proper reputation to upvote your answer Sorry bro.

Comment: where is `document ` coming from?

Comment: @DavidSeek Look closely: `document` is only used in `page.evaluate`; this method executes function that you pass to it *inside of a web page context*. It's just like you could run commands in Devtools console. And `document` is a top-level element of DOM, hence can be accessed via javascript running on a web page.

Comment: gotya. thank you for taking the time and getting back to me